# Independence and repartition of some variables

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

I have some problems in doing a homework at Probabilities.

The exercise:

Let A, B, C be independent random variables with N( 0, 1 ) repartition.

Let M, N, P be:

```
M = ( 1/sqrt( 2 ) )*( A - B )
N = ( 1/sqrt( 6 ) )*( A + B - 2C )
P = ( 1/sqrt( 3 ) )*( A + B + C )
```

Prove that M, N, P have N( 0, 1 ) repartition and they are independent.

I've tried so far the method with the equation system, getting the inverse and calculating the Jacobian but i have so big numbers that i can't continue to 'brutefore' this way.
The teacher told me it is an easier way but i don't see it.
Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that

1. *Linear transformations* of *jointly normal* random variables result in *jointly normal* random variables,

and

2. Independent normal random variables are a subclass of jointly normal random variables.

So, assert that $M,N,P$ are jointly normal random variables because $A,B,C$ are jointly normal random variables. Then, find $\Sigma_{M,N,P}$, the *covariance* matrix of $M,N,P$ from $\Sigma_{A,B,C}$, the covariance matrix of $A,B,C$. Hint: $\Sigma_{A,B,C}$ is the identity matrix.  If $\Sigma_{M,N,P}$ turns out to be the identity matrix and the means of $M,N,P$ all happen to be $0$, you are done: you have proved that $M,N,P$ are independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.

Further hints: You will find the formulas
$$E\big[aX+bY+cZ\big] = aE[X]+bE[Y]+cE[Z]$$
and, for *independent* $X,Y,Z$,
\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(aX+bY+cZ,dX+eY+fZ) &= 
ad\operatorname{var}(X)+be\operatorname{var}(Y)+cf\operatorname{var}(Z)
\end{align}
to be useful results that will save you a lot of work if you apply them judiciously.